# UI5 extension project in BAS appears to be incomplete

Tags: sapui5, sap-business-application-studio

I have created a UI5 extension project 'pmroffers.variant1' in Business Application Studio for Fiori Standard App 'Promotional Offers: Fiori ID F2053'. At first sight everything looked fine.

Now, when right-clicking on 'proffers.variant1' and selecting menu item 'Create Extension' I get error message 'The '.extconfig.json' file does not include the required data for this process to continue in SAP Business Application Studio.'

When right-clicking directly on the '.extconfig.json' file, I get the extension selection but it is missing entries for 'Replace Service' and 'i18n Text Customization' that we used to have in Web IDE. Also, when clicking on 'Extend View/Fragment', clicking 'Next' and selecting View 'General' it shows message 'There are no extension points available' even though I know that this is incorrect since I have used them when extending the very same app in Web IDE:

So am I missing something or is this worth creating an OSS ticket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAP Support helped us to find the solution to the problem:

Apparently, when creating an extension point, the extension wizard requests to load the view that needs to be extended from the backend end server in order to evaluate its XML for extension tags. In our scenario, the backend system returned an authorization error (due to missing SAML authentication) for this request.

The solution for us was to change the destination to the backend to 'principal propagation'.